# phonegap generic push ios alert when app is active

Tags: cordova, push-notification

I have phonegap app using [push plugin](https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin) , running on iphone. Problem is when a notification is received, alert window appears.
What I expect is

1- app is running in background mode or sleep, push alert should display. this works

2- app is active and running on front/foreground, on push notification message, no alert message should appear. as it is now, it display alert `navigator.notification.alert(event.alert);` message on each notification.

so question is how to skip notification alert if app is running and active foreground?
or any event when app move to background by pressing home button on iphone where I can handle or change alert code...?

Answer (score 0):

You should handle the [pause](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/cordova/events/events.html#pause) and [resume](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/cordova/events/events.html#resume) cordova events and add your logic to them. There are full examples in the cordova docs.